Help wiring new kitchen light fitting
Looking for support in changing my kitchen light fitting. Image attached of old light connections and new. Which wires here need to which connection in the new fitting? The mic of red and black has confused me! 

Is there a switch controlling this light.  The live and neutral connected together and to the light wires is odd.  Old style US switch loops connect L & N at the ceiling, but not to wires from the light.  Possible the wiring is messed up, using the L/N colours for the others use.  I think old English wiring code used red for live, black for neutral and the new light is using the newer code colours.

Where are you located? Wire colors and 220V / 50Hz fixture suggest you are in the UK, EU, Australia, elswhere outside the Americas. (I might guess UK from the connectors.)

Hi, I'm located in the UK :)
